# How to solve Duplicate resources

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, flutter

Hello i managed to fix the problem with the google services i have ran into another problem when i run the app this is what comes up

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Duplicate resources","sources":[{"file":{"description":"string/default_web_client_id","path":"C:\flutter\flutter_app\flutter_app\NocturnlHouse\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml"}},{"file":{"description":"string/default_web_client_id","path":"C:\flutter\flutter_app\flutter_app\NocturnlHouse\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml"}}],"tool":"Resource and asset merger"}